# Gradient tends to zero in gradient descent/flow?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\bf{R}^d\to\bf{R}$ be $C^1$ and such that $f(x)>-c$ for some $c\in\bf{R}$ and any $x\in\bf{R}^d$. Consider
$$
\frac{d}{dt}x(t) = -\nabla f(x(t))
$$
for $x\geq0$. Then we can conclude two things:

- the map $t\mapsto f(x(t))$ is non-increasing
- $f(x(t))$ converges to some constant as $t\to+\infty$

My question is:

> is it true (and why) that $\|\nabla f(x(t))\|\to0$ as $t\to+\infty$?

Comment: I would write the linear approximation of the function using the gradient, then consider your second bullet. That should do it?

Comment: @cheyne thank you for your comment, but would you mind adding a bit more detail, I am not quite sure which function you are referring to.

Comment: OK, but first, you mean $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ right?

Comment: sorry $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ ...and $t >0$?